# Android trace error

Tags: android, android-emulator

During android development I am getting the following error and my application will not load

```
error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

What could be the cause?

Comment: We'll need more information that what you're giving us right now. OS, code and other attached systems.

Comment: That seems like the standard `/traces/ANR.txt` not found error, which your app shouldn't need, and shouldn't be preventing it from loading. If this is what this is about, I'd say the app is crashing somewhere else. Please post the full stack trace.